# How can I convert a html text to utf-8 with C#

Tags: c#, utf-8, iso-8859-1

How can I convert my input value

> Itâ€™s time for Events This Weekend. Browse through and see which events are happening around you. Have fun Ciao! LoudNProudLive Series: â€˜Hit Makersâ€™ Special Edition LoudNProudLive Series presents a â€˜Hit Makersâ€™ Special Edition with headliners Tolu (of Project Fame), Simi and Oyinkanade. Date: Thursday, April 30, 2015 Time: 8 PM Venue: ELIAS (Ocean Bay Mall), […]

to a human readable sentence in utf-8. I tried the code below and this was what I got. -

> It�s time for Events This Weekend. Browse through and see which events are happening around you. Have fun Ciao! LoudNProudLive Series: �Hit Makers� Special Edition LoudNProudLive Series presents a �Hit Makers� Special Edition with headliners Tolu (of Project Fame), Simi and Oyinkanade. Date: Thursday, April 30, 2015 Time: 8 PM Venue: ELIAS (Ocean Bay Mall), […]

```
 //convert html to utf-8
    private static string cleanUpCodes(string value)
    {
        //convert from iso to utf-8
        Encoding iso = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1252");
        Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;
        byte[] isoBytes = iso.GetBytes(value);
        byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.Convert(utf8, iso, isoBytes);
        string msg = utf8.GetString(utf8Bytes);

        //convert to real html
        msg = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(msg);

        return msg;
    }
```

Comment: If the source encoding is indeed windows-1252, that should be right. What makes you think that the source document is in windows-1252 encoding though? I would guess it's UTF-16LE by the looks of things, but best is just to find out what it is.

Answer (score 4):

Presumably this has been decoded using the wrong encoding, hence the weird text.  In this case, you don't want to `Convert` between encodings, you just want to get your bytes back and have another go:

For example:

```
var bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(value);
var result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

That gives this, which is pretty close:

> It’s time for Events This Weekend. Browse through and see which events are happening around you. Have fun Ciao! LoudNProudLive Series: ‘Hit Makers’ Special Edition LoudNProudLive Series presents a ‘Hit Makers’ Special Edition with headliners Tolu (of Project Fame), Simi and Oyinkanade. Date: Thursday, April 30, 2015 Time: 8 PM Venue: ELIAS (Ocean Bay Mall), [�]

I'd be inclined to get to the source of the problem though - how did you get this string?

Comment: I got it from an rss feed

Comment: Could you provide a link and show how you're reading it?  I'd be surprised if this couldn't be solved by changing this rather than having to post-process it.